# Hide pop-up by clicking outside it (problems with Philip Waltons solution)

Tags: javascript

I know the question of closing a pop-up by clicking outside of it has been asked before. I have a somewhat complex pop-up and the solution offered by Phillip Walton isn't working for me.

His code simply made my page blurry but stopped the popup from appearing.

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
if (!$(event.target).closest('.maincontainer').length) {
popup.classList.remove('popup--open');
popup.style.display = 'none';
popupAccessory.style.display = 'none';
popupAccessory.classList.remove('popup--accessory--open');
maincontainer.classList.remove('blurfilter');
}
});
```

I also tried:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
if (event.target != popup)  {
popup.classList.remove('popup--open');
popup.style.display = 'none';
popupAccessory.style.display = 'none';
popupAccessory.classList.remove('popup--accessory--open');
maincontainer.classList.remove('blurfilter');
}
}, true);
```

This closes the popup when I click anywhere, including on the popup itself. I want it to close only when I click on part of the screen that isn't the popup.
The code to open the popup:

```
function openpopup() {
popup.style.display = 'initial';
setTimeout(function(){
popup.classList.add('popup--open');
popup.style.boxShadow = '0 0 45px 2px white';
maincontainer.classList.add('blurfilter')}, 10);

for (let i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++ ) {
setTimeout(function() {
  listitems[i].classList.add('visible');
}, 100);
}
}
```

I added the event listener to a button

```
popupOpenbtn.addEventListener('click', openpopup);
```

The HTML structure:-

```
<div class="maincontainer> 
...all my page content... 
</div>

<div class="popup"> 
...popup contents...
</div
```

Comment: add relevant HTML

Comment: *added relevant HTML* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using only css classes to style your popup and use JS only to add, remove and toggle that class. Not sure how close to your working exercise is this fiddle but I've prepared this to show how the document/window click event can be checked to successfully open/close the popup window.

```js
var popupOverlay = document.querySelector('#popup__overlay');

var popupOpenButton = document.querySelector('#popupOpenButton');
var popupCloseButton = document.querySelector('#popupCloseButton');
var mainContainer = document.querySelector('main');

function closestById(el, id) {
  while (el.id != id) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (!el) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return el;
}

popupOpenButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
  popupOverlay.classList.toggle('isVisible');
});

popupCloseButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  popupOverlay.classList.toggle('isVisible');
});

mainContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (popupOverlay.classList.contains('isVisible') && !closestById(event.target, 'popup__overlay') && event.target !== popupOpenButton) {
    popupOverlay.classList.toggle('isVisible');
  }
});
```

```css
#popup__overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  z-index: 9999;
  text-align: center;
}

#popup__overlay.isVisible {
  display: block;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<aside id="popup__overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Popup title</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum
    </p>
    <button id="popupCloseButton">Close popup</button>
  </div>

</aside>

<main>
  <div class="buttonWrapper">
    <button id="popupOpenButton">Open popup</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks David. I may end up using stop propogation out of desperation but the whole thrust of Philip Waltons article is that this method is problematic. https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/ Let me know if you have any thoughts on this

Comment: Solution comes separating the popup in an `aside` and the `main` content in a main tag. Now both tags are the root for the pop up and the normal content so they can have event listeners that go to different parents and they don't collide between them.

Note: main has a forced height to occupy all body content and so being clickable.

Comment: Changing my code to use maincontainer rather than window has worked :D